# Drawing canvas in an element that has just been added

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In my main.html I am replacing the content div with the following piece.

```
<div id="content">
    <canvas id="field" width="400px" height="600px"></canvas>
</div>
```

I  want that, after the html has been replaced, the function is executed and the rectangle gets drawn. Currently I have this, but it is not working.

```
$("#line_up").click(function() {
    $("#content").load("../html/line_up.html #content > *");
    loadCanvas();
});

function loadCanvas() {
    var x = document.getElementById("field");
    field = x.getContext('2d');
    field.strokeRect(10, 10, 280, 280);
}
```

Thank guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an asynchronous call, you need to wait to write to the canvas after it is loaded

```
$("#line_up").click(function() {
    $("#content").load("../html/line_up.html #content > *", loadCanvas);
});
```